# Show content form database related to user's selection (laravel)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Maybe someone can help me with my problem? All I need is to show related div with content based on user’s selection.

For instance, user choose

```
@foreach($modules as $module)
    <option value="{{ $module->id}}" >{{$module->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Below shows content related to this module, choose module 2 and shows module 2.

I presume I can do it with ajax or jQuery, but all I tried doesn't work. My logic in view is:

```
 <span>Module:</span>
<select class="dropdownHeader function" id="type" name="type">
 @foreach($modules as $module)
 <option value="{{ $module->id}}" >{{$module->name }}</option>
@endforeach
 </select>
   @foreach($modules as $module)
<div id="moduleType">
<span>Database:{!! Form::text('database',isset($module->DB)? $module->DB : old('DB'),['placeholder' =>'Database'])!!}<br/> <br/></span>
<span>Path:{!! Form::text('path',isset($module->path)? $module->path : old('PATH'),['placeholder' =>'Path'])!!}
<br/><br/></span>
 </div>
 </li>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Have you tried to call a ajax request on every change on the select?
Call a Controller that will seek the "module" by the ID of the selected one and returns the "module" info. Them you'll change the spans with the new module infos.

Comment: No, I not sure how to do it.
I tried to use jquery but it was not successful.

Comment: Just FYI, It looks like you have some closing tag issues i.e. `</li></div>` before the last `@endforeach`.

Comment: It's not hard to make a Ajax request, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
On your server side you will set a Controller and then a route to access it.
Put it on URL from ajax request like "url:'{{route('YOUR NEW ROUTE NAME')}}"
type: your url type, GET, POST... etc

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to figure out with ajax!
At this moment works for me with jquery:
 <select id="type" name="type">
 @foreach($modules as $module)
 <option value="{{$module->id}}" >{{$module->name}}</option>@endforeach
</select>
     @foreach($modules as $module)
    <div id="module-{{$module->id}}"  class="module">
     <span>Database: {!! Form::text('database',isset($module->DB)? $module->DB : old('DB'),['placeholder' =>'Database'])!!}</span></div>@endforeach

Comment: <script>
    $(function() {
        let modules = $('.module').hide();

        $('#type').on('change', function() {
            let value = $(this).val();
            modules.hide();
            $('#module-' + value).show();
        });
    });
</script>